# How to compare two columns from different tables in trigger postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to create a trigger, where inserted certain value in column if one value "currentAttemptCount" becomes equal or more to another "attemptCountLimit" from another table

i have two tables

```
@Table(name = "course_items")
public class CourseItem {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "course_item_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "attempt_count_limit")
    private Integer attemptCountLimit;

@Table(name = "work_course_items")
public abstract class WorkCourseItem {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "work_course_item_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected Integer id;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    protected CourseItemState state;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "course_item_id", referencedColumnName = "course_item_id")
    protected CourseItem courseItem;
    @Column(name = "current_attempt_count")
    protected Integer currentAttemptCount;
```

and how should i compare those values? trying something like next, because INNER JOIN doesn't seem necessary in trigger

```
    IF ((SELECT attempt_count_limit
         FROM "ts".course_items
         WHERE course_items.course_item_id = new.course_item_id) <=
        (SELECT current_attempt_count
         FROM "ts".work_course_items
         WHERE work_course_items.work_course_item_id = new.work_course_id))
    THEN
      UPDATE "ts".work_course_items
      SET state = 'YEAP_IT_IS'
      WHERE work_course_item_id = new.work_course_item_id;

    END IF;
    RETURN new;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER quiz_attempt_count
   BEFORE UPDATE OF state
   ON "ts".work_course_items
   FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE change_work_course_state();
```

Comment: Will be better public tables structure as SQL (DDL) statement instead code

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can compare two col from diff tbs

**PL/pgSQL Example:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION change_work_course_state() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
  IF EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM "ts".course_items ci
    JOIN "ts".work_course_items wci
    ON ci.course_item_id = new.course_item_id
    WHERE ci.attempt_count_limit <= wci.current_attempt_count
  ) THEN
    UPDATE "ts".work_course_items
    SET state = 'YEAP_IT_IS'
    WHERE work_course_item_id = new.work_course_item_id;
  END IF;

  RETURN new;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

CREATE TRIGGER quiz_attempt_count
BEFORE UPDATE OF state
ON "ts".work_course_items
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE change_work_course_state();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an update event that happens when a `work_course_items` record is being updated. So, you have a single record from this table to operate with inside your `trigger`. Hence, your `IF` is superfluous:

```
    IF ((SELECT attempt_count_limit
         FROM "ts".course_items
         WHERE course_items.course_item_id = new.course_item_id) <=
        (SELECT current_attempt_count
         FROM "ts".work_course_items
         WHERE work_course_items.work_course_item_id = new.work_course_id))
```

Instead of the second query, you could simply pass `new.current_attempt_count` to your `procedure, because you already have that value in the trigger.

As about your first query, its logic is correct.

You will need to actually try anything that you implement and make sure that it works properly though.

Answer (score 0):

Do not issue *update ... set state ...* within a trigger that has fired because of a dml statement **update ... set state ...**. This will cause the trigger to fire again, which in turn will cause the trigger fire again. then again and again and ... Resulting in a never ending loop of trigger firing the trigger (well eventually you exhaust resources and the statement is aborted, with nothing accomplished). Moreover it is absolutely not necessary - you have everything needed in the NEW row image. So

```
create or replace function change_work_course_state() 
  returns trigger 
 language plpgsql
as $$
begin
  if exists (
             select null 
               from ts.course_items ci
              where ci.course_item_id = new.course_item_id
                and ci.attempt_count_limit <= new.current_attempt_count
            ) 
     then
        new.state = 'YEAP_IT_IS'
  end if;

  return new;
end;
$$;
```